# Doctrine Relationships - referenced Column name as identifier for entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, foreign-key-relationship

So I have these 2 Bundles:

- `UserBundle`
- `BlogBundle`

and these 3 Entities:

- `UserBundle:User`
- `BlogBundle:User`
- `BlogBundle:Article`

`BlogBundle:User` extends `UserBundle:User` using a bidirectional one to one relationship. The join column name is `user_id` and it is an association key:

```
BlogBundle\Entity\User:
type: entity
table: blog_users
id:
    user:
        associationKey: true
oneToOne:
    user:
        targetEntity: UserBundle\Entity\User
        inversedBy: blog_user
        joinColumn:
            name: user_id
            referencedColumnName: id
```

Now I want to create a bidirectional one to Many relationship between `BlogBundle:User` and `BlogBundle:Article`.

**Currently I'm trying this:**

```
BlogBundle:User
oneToMany:
    articles:
        targetEntity: Article
        mappedBy: author

BlogBundle:Article
manyToOne:
    author:
        targetEntity: User
        inversedBy: Article
        joinColumn:
            name: author
            referencedColumnName: user_id
```

**My Problem** is, it works, I can access data from `UserBundle:User` through an `Article` object, but in the profiler it shows them as not mapped correctly. My guess is it would be possible to do what I'm trying, but I'm just doing something wrong.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with the inversedBy, where you have to write the name of the field, not the name of the entity.

Here que documentation: 
http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional

Your code will be:

```
BlogBundle:User
  oneToMany:
    articles:
      targetEntity: Article
      mappedBy: author

BlogBundle:Article
  manyToOne:
    author:
      targetEntity: User
      inversedBy: articles
      joinColumn:
        name: author
        referencedColumnName: user_id
```